# Ionic event listener fires on every screen, only want is to apply to one controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

in my ionic application I am binding my using the following code to implement a device back button:

```
var deregister = $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(
   function () {
       toastr.warning("Back button pressed");
   }, 100
);
$scope.$on('$pause', deregister);
```

The function executes when I tap on the back button, but it executes on every other screen as well. I only want it to apply to the controller I am using it in. Is there any way that I can accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

The reason that I am trying to implement this is that after the application is installed the first time, my device back button event does not fire if I want to exit the application. Splash page is displayed, login screen shown, then with correct credentials home screen is shown. I clear the history on login and home. On home the back button does not work. When I add the back button event listener, the event is applied on all the screens, not just the controller I use this code in. That is the problem.

Comment: You can use $state to check the current page and then execute the function body conditionally..

Answer (score 0):

```
var deregister = $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(
   function () {
       toastr.warning("Back button pressed");
       $scope.$$listeners.$pause=[];
   }, 100
);
$scope.$on('$pause', deregister);
```

Untested code and I'm not sure if it fits your scenario, but you can unbind the event in the event handler so that it only gets executed once?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my answer with my scenario. I am trying to implement this to rid myself of another weird issue I'm having.